# Using CMD Command in C# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, path, directory, cmd

I want to use CMD command in c# winforms to create a folder to a DIR, with a given directory path,

e.g.

> "C:\temp> MD MyFolder"

I wonder how can i execute it using c# win forms platform. I tried looking at google but couldn't find anything, and is it a good practise to use it, the only reason i wanna use it beacause my directory path is too long for `Directory.CreateDirectory()` method.

I worked out that CMD have the same limitations as "CreateDirectory" method in C#.
Thanks for your comment and answers people.

Comment: Why do you need to do this via DOS command? Why not simply use the .NET equivalents?

Comment: Maximum path length is not a property of `Directory.CreateDirectory`, you won't be able to bypass it by using a different way to create the directory.

Comment: Hi, I believe dos has 8.3 file system length limitation, but .net is ok with 256 characters. I do not see a problem here.

Comment: You should think about how make your directory path shorter instead of finding some kind of workaround.

Comment: @unruledboy cmd.exe is not DOS and even DOS subsystem from Win9x supports LFN on FAT.

Comment: @Marco - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx): PathTooLongException - The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length. (and note the  **system-defined**)

Comment: Why mark him down, the question is pretty clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these answers about `Process.Start` are wonderful, but I am afraid that we are before yet one more case of an OP asking us to help them implement the solution which they *think* is going to do what they are trying to achieve instead of asking us how to achieve what they are *really* trying to achieve.

Luckily, the OP has included enough information so that we can guess what they are trying to achieve and give them an answer which might actually be useful to them.

So:

- My very first recommendation would be that you fix your directory path so that it is not too long for the `Directory.CreateDirectory()` method, because that's insane, and it is bound to sooner or later cause you problems that you are going to bitterly regret for.
- If you insist on creating your directory someplace close to the root, use the very fine `System.IO.Path.Combine()` method, to build the full path to your directory, so that you can call `Directory.CreateDirectory()`, instead of trying to create it from within the current directory in which your application is running, or coming up with bizarre ideas about launching a command processor to create your directory for you.

Also, please forget about DOS. These commands have been called `console commands` for the last 18 years, ever since the release of Windows NT 3.1 back in 1993.

Comment: @ Mike Nakis thanks for your meaningful answer , Actually i am trying to download Document libraries of a Sharepoint site, which have webs and its subwebs and so on, so there is no way i can fix directory path, even tho I tried to reduce it, or use directoryinfo, or setting current directory, non of them actually worked.
and i am going to give a go for "System.IO.Path.Combine()" as I never used it before.
oh btw your right, I thought CMD might have more control but it got same restrictions as .NET.

Comment: I Looked into Combine path, but what I get from it is , its combining string paths but when I will use create directory it will be using same full path again, as i think its the limitation of createDirectory method.

Comment: OK, I see. I have come across this situation before, and you are right, when you duplicate web structures you have no control over the depth of your paths, so `C:\temp\` is necessary to use as a root.

Comment: I believe that the limitation of the CreateDirectory method corresponds to a limitation of the underlying filesystem, so I do not think you will be able to gain anything if you try any other way. Are you serious? The paths you have are too long for CreateDirectory even if you put them under a 'C:\temp\' root?

Comment: I wonder if using "C:\temp" will actually going to solve the problem sir ?

Comment: In that case you might have to go with an altogether different strategy, for example storing all the downloaded files in one flat directory, (giving them unique names,) and maintaining a `Dictionary<string,string>` which maps the URL of each file to the actual filename under which you ended up saving it.

Comment: I get what you mean sir. I probably consider trying it once I give up on finding a way to downloading them in a way i want them, and am pretty sure we can trick computer somehow :), as if i will save them in one parallel directory there is a chance of getting duplicate folders or i will loose the count (in short words it will get really complicated and for clients i am making this app, wont be really happy) thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

To overcome the 256 characters limit, I once wrote a [tiny library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/bugs/ZetaLongPaths.aspx).

Basically this library contains several P/Invoke wrappers to underlying Win32 functions that automatically prepend the `\\?\` suffix to indicate a path longer than `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: @wRAR to my knowledge the Win32/Platform SDK functions does not make me as the developer think about that when it comes to plain file copy/creation etc. (beside permission stuff). Am I wrong on this?

Comment: Congratulations for swatting a fly with a Buick. (Or maybe with an Aircraft Carrier.)

Comment: @MikeNakis Sorry, being no native US American and only driving a Volkswagen; what does your saying mean?

Comment: @ Uwe Keim, thanks for your answer,i looked at your blog which gives information about prefix "\\?\" but its not telling how to change the windows API or its just me who missed how to use this in my application, Cheers

Comment: @UweKeim I am not American either, but this is a very popular expression. "Swat a fly with a hammer / sledge hammer / buick / tactical thermonuclear bomb" is [an idiom for doing something in an unnecessarily complicated way.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43372/whats-an-idiom-for-doing-something-in-an-unnecessarily-complicated-way) (The Aircraft Carrier analogy was of my own device.)

Comment: @MikeNakis Thank you. For me, the library often was the only available solution, so I created it. Based on which facts do you judge this  library being unnecessary?

Comment: @UweKeim Based on my firm belief that the OP should be able to find a one-liner solution in C#, and a one-liner in C# beats the complexity, the burden, and the incompatibility of using P/Invoke any day.

Comment: @MikeNakis, the BCL does not support long paths, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2008/07/07/long-paths-in-net-part-3-of-3-redux-kim-hamilton.aspx - there is no good "one liner" solution to bypass this inherent limitation of the `System.IO` namespace as it's currently implemented.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the link. The OP might be able to find a solution based on that reading.

Comment: @UweKeim No, I meant "how such long paths will work with FAT/NTFS", mostly because I am too lazy to look for maximum path lengths for these FSes.

Comment: @wRAR The 256 (or actually, 260) limit is independent of FAT/NTFS, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

To make command line process use it:

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
    }
};
```

Now for data handling use this:

```
// For output data directly from command line.
process.OutputDataReceived += outputReceivedHandler;
process.BeginOutputReadLine();

// For error output directly from command line.
process.ErrorDataReceived += errorReceivedHandler;
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

// For providing an command to command line.
var command = "ping www.google.pl";
var writer = process.StandardInput;
writer.WriteLine(command);

process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Finally method that listening for output:

```
public void outputReceivedHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

Of course this same for error handling. Hope this can help anybody. I searching that a lot and I don't found the answer, only some directions for make it, now I can help another people who has this same problem. Sorry if my language is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to execute an external executable. In the case of built in commands you need to make sure that you start it with the `cmd.exe` executable (passing in the parameters with the `/c` flag).

Note that an OS limit can't be overcome with this method either.

Comment: I don't think `MD` is an executable.

Comment: @wRAR - no, it's a built-in command, so (as mentioned) you need to call `cmd.exe` with some extra params.

Comment: @HansKesting - And with the `/c` flag.

Comment: @Hans Kesting I was commenting the first version of the answer.

Comment: @wRAR - Thanks for the comment. You are quite right - MD is built in.

Comment: @Oded You either start cmd directly or run a command via the shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c MD C:\\YourFolder");
```

btw. I really do not get what you mean by "Directory.CreateDirectory does not work".

Answer (score 0):

This will run the command, the cmd window will be hidden as well, I have used this a lot and it works flawlessly.

```
ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe"); 
cmd.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
cmd.RedirectStandardError = true; 
cmd.UseShellExecute = false; 
cmd.CreateNoWindow = true; 
cmd.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
Process console = Process.Start(cmd); 
console.StandardInput.WriteLine("md MyFolder");
```

Hope this helps!